# Create thumbnails on the fly with cache or on upload?

Tags: php, thumbnails

I'm currently rewriting a website that need a lot of different sizes for each images. In the past I was doing it by creating the thumbnails images for all sizes on the upload. But now I have a doubt about is performance. This is because now I have to change my design and half of my images are not of the right size. So I think of 2 solutions :

1. Keep doing this and add a button on the backend to re-generate all the images. The problem is that I always need to know every sizes needed by every part of the site.
2. Only upload the real size image, and when displaying it, put in the SRC tag something like sr="thumbs.php?img=my-image-path/image.jpg&width=120&height=120". Then create the thumb and display it. Also my script would check if the thumb already exists, if it does it doesn't need to recrate it so just display it. Each 5 Days launch a script with a crontask to delete all the thumbs (to be sure to only use the usefull ones).

I think that the second solution is better but I'm a little concern by the fact that I need to call php everytime an image is shown, even if it's already created, it's php that give it to display...

Thanks for your advises

Comment: Go for second approach , it might be slow for 1st time but its good that you dont resize images unnecessary which are never going to be used , one cons is slow when image is access 1st time .

Comment: So you want to improve performance and decides its a good idea to regenerate all thumbnails every time someone visits a page? Think about it.

Comment: It really depends.  What is most important to you - upload performance or display performance?  Do you have a high variability in thumbnail size to where pre-generating the thumbs is going to not be practical? What sort of traffic pattern do you have.  Are users comiong to your pages over and over again where high cacheability matters or are they one-time visitors to where getting the images to them to download the first time as quickly as possbile matters? Have you looked into generating thumbs with an asynchronous process so that it doesn't impact upload performance?

Comment: If the existing thumbnails are not good just write a script that will recreate them all with the new specifications. Even if it take a couple hours to run it's still better than resampling images every time someone want them. Resampling images draw your server CPU like nothing else.

Comment: @MikeBrant you can easily improve display performance trough  caching of already rendered images. I see no reason for generating muliple images in advance

Comment: @hek2mgl It really depends on how the site is used. If for example you wanted to leverage a CDN, then having a `src` attribute which points to a server-side script is not even feasible. Similarly, maybe one doesn't want the overhead of calling PHP to determine if a cached image does or does not exist. I was just asking questions which the OP did not specify to help him thing about considerations that should be made when making the decision. I was not implying that one solution is best, as we simply don't know enough here.

Comment: (thanks for your comments). So to be more clear, In my idea of the option 2, the image are NOT recreate for every visitors. They are render the first time a visitor access the page, then as it's already created and store in a Thumbs folder, the php script will only display the already created one. And I will delete all the "old" thumbs every XX days. Then when a new visitor see the page it will generate again the thumb. So it's not for every visitor but once everytime the thumb doesn't already exists.

Comment: @MikeBrant `If for example you wanted to leverage a CDN, then having a src attribute which points to a server-side script is not even feasible.` Why? (I'm just asking)

Comment: @MikeBrant, my concern is about the good convention to use. In my case I will have 6 thumbs versions for each images. It's not a big site project, it's a classic one to present a company with a gallery, a blog, a products catalog and some little things.

Comment: @hek2mgl If one is using a CDN, typically they would not have a way to run a script such as PHP on the CDN servers.

Comment: @MikeBrant I'm just getting into that CDN stuff.. Thanks

Comment: @Mushr00m So for your use-case you are probably talking about a relatively low-volume site, and probably are not talking about global distribution of content, so the on-demand generation may be fine for your (perhaps even with a script to "crawl" the site to pre-generate the images if you wanted to).  For purposes of the question (which future readers may see), I wanted to comment on different aspects for consideration.

Comment: @MikeBrant What you are taking into account in order to be compatible with multiple environments such as CDN or even just development is very interesting. It would be great if you could craft an answer and elaborate a bit on that.. (if you are too lazy for that now, no problem ;)

Comment: @hek2mgl I did add an answer in case you are interested.

Comment: Enterprisey Answer: Use a job queue/server to scale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the second option, if you don't have too much storage and first if you don't have too much CPU.

Or you can combine these: generate and store the image at the first open of the php thumbnails generator and nex time just give back the cached image.

With this solution you'll have only the necessary images and if you want you can delete sometimes the older ones.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the original question and subsequent comments, it would sound like on-demand generation would be suitable for you, as it doesn't sound like you will have a demanding environment in terms of absolutely minimizing the amount of download time to the end client.

It seems you already have a grasp around the option to give your `<img>` tags a `src` value that is a PHP script, with that script either serving up a cached thumbnail if it exists, or generating it on the fly, caching it, and then serving it up, so let me give you another option.

Generally speaking, utilizing PHP to serve up static resources is not a great idea as you begin to scale your site as

1. This would require the additional overhead of invoking PHP to serve these sorts of requests, something much more optimized with the basic web server like Apache, Nginx, etc. This means your site is going to be able to handle less traffic per server because it is using extra memory, CPU, etc. in order to serve up this static content.
2. It makes it hard to move those static resources into a single repository outside of the server for serving up content (such as CDN). This means you have to duplicate your files on each and every web server you have powering a site.

As such, my suggestion would be to still serve up the images as static image files via the webserver, but generate thumbnails on the fly if they are missing. To achieve this you can simply create a custom redirect rule or 404 handler on the web server, such that requests in your thumbnail directory which do not match an existing thumbnail image could be redirected to a PHP script to automatically generate the thumbnail and serve up the image (without the browser even knowing it).  Future requests against this thumbnail would be served up as a static image.

This scales quite nicely as, if in the future you have the need to move your static images to a single server (or CDN), you can just use an origin-pull mechanism to try to get the content from your main servers, which will auto-generate them via the same mechanism I just mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! :) What do you think about multiple web servers having the same NAS storage mounted for that purpose (storing images, creating them on demand) ? Do you have experience with performance when the NAS has to handle concurrent access? (I'm having s3 from AWS in mind, using s3fs fuse plugin)

Comment: @hek2mgl Just relying on NAS would likely be very slow in serving up the images.  Luckily for you, there is a solution for S3 to make this a little more tolerable and actually give you local disk performance.  Take a look at s3fs ( http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/ ). This allows you to mount an S3 bucket on the local file system so you can access it like a local drive.  This is still slow, but it has a caching mechanism to cache files into a true local directory for increased performance.

Comment: @hek2mgl Heh. I guess I totally glossed over your mention of s3fs in the your initial comment :)

Comment: @hek2mgl  If you are at the point of scaling like that, you may be at the point to simply consider using Cloudfront in front of your S3 bucket.  The only drawback to using S3 as origin-pull is that you wouldn't be able to automatically generate thumbnails as you could if you were using a dedicated webserver. In such a case, I would probably consider using an asynchronous (i.e. cron) process to generate thumbs if generating them on upload wasn't an option.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, was on my way home from work. Many thanks for your advices! Currently  playing around with AWS services and not being totally sure what services I should use. I also have  the requirement to share dynamically generated files between webserver instances. Will have look into the cloudfront service.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, i'm concidering using the second option with HTACCESS to generate the missing thumbs as you suggest... But need to test more on this subject. I feel more confortable using only PHP in SRC but maybe it's a false true ^^

Comment: @Mushr00m The redirect method is in essence the same as the PHP script method that you suggest insofar as the PHP script that one would be directed to would need to inspect the request URI and know how to generate and serve up the thumbnail as requested (with proper content type and cache-control headers).  The main difference is that you get away from having to use PHP at all for those cases where the image already exists.